# SHA256 in Go and PHP giving different results

Tags: php, go, sha, sha256

I'm trying to send a SHA256 hashed string over HTTP to a server, where I want to authenticate by performing a SHA256 hash and verifying the two match.  For testing purposes I'm using the same string, however my results do not match up.  Could this be something with default encoding schemes for my base64_encode calls?  Thanks.

In PHP I'm doing:

```
$sha = hash("sha256", $url, true);
$sha = base64_encode(urlencode($sha));
```

And in Go I'm doing

```
//convert string to byte slice
converted := []byte(to_hash)

//hash the byte slice and return the resulting string
hasher := sha256.New()
hasher.Write(converted)
return (base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil)))
```

Comment: make sure the two strings are absolutely identical before you start working on them. you could have a hidden char (linebreak, space, tab, etc...) at the tail end in one of the languages, which will completely alter the hash value.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same string encoding.

Comment: I'm using the word "test" hardcoded in on both sides just to make sure, still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure it out after a while.  I standardized both to hexadecimal encoding.  To accomplish this I changed the code as follows:

PHP:

```
$sha = hash("sha256", $url, false); //false is default and returns hex
//$sha = base64_encode(urlencode($sha)); //removed
```

Go:

```
//convert string to byte slice
converted := []byte(to_hash)

//hash the byte slice and return the resulting string
hasher := sha256.New()
hasher.Write(converted)
return (hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))) //changed to hex and removed URLEncoding
```