# How to compare [32]byte with []byte?

Tags: go, sha256

I want to compare output of `sha256.Sum256()` which is `[32]byte` with a `[]byte`.

I am getting an error "mismatched types [32]byte and []byte". I am not able to convert `[]byte` to `[32]byte`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can trivially convert any array ([size]T) to a slice ([]T) by slicing it:

```
x := [32]byte{}
slice := x[:] // shorthand for x[0:len(x)]
```

From there you can compare it to your slice like you would compare any other two slices, e.g.

```
func Equal(slice1, slice2 []byte) bool {
    if len(slice1) != len(slice2) {
        return false
    }

    for i := range slice1 {
        if slice1[i] != slice2[i] {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Edit: As Dave mentions in the comments, there's also an `Equal` method in the `bytes` package, `bytes.Equal(x[:], y[:])`

Comment: You can also use `bytes.Equal(x[:], y[:])`

Answer (score -4):

I got the answer using this thread

[SHA256 in Go and PHP giving different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111754/sha256-in-go-and-php-giving-different-results?rq=1)

```
    converted := []byte(raw)
    hasher := sha256.New()
    hasher.Write(converted)
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil)) == encoded
```

This is not converting [32]byte to []byte but it is using different function which do not give output in [32]byte.

Comment: This might not be applicable to the original question, if `encoded` is a slice of uninterpreted bytes.  It only works if `encoded` is to be interpreted as the base64-encoding of the checksum.