# Use string constant as byte value in array or slice literal

Tags: go, sha256

I am trying to make a global byte array from a string with:

```
point := []byte{0x23f32...}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
untyped string constant "0x23f32...) as byte value in array or slice literal
```

I know what I should use a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a string to a slice of bytes, i.e. use of `()` instead of `{}`.

```
point := []byte(0x23f32...)
```

The code in the question is a composite literal. However, I am using operators as a global variable, so I think that I cannot declare the variable that way. Also, further in the code, logically, I will also have to use `[33]byte`, so I'm worried about how to declare `point []byte` here so that I don't have a type error later like ["mismatched types [32]byte and []byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762562/how-to-compare-32byte-with-byte-in-golang).

So keeping these two questions in mind, could you please tell me how to deal with `point := []byte` here correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`0x23f32...` is a integer literal and won't convert to a byte (or bytes). You will get this compile-time error for `var point = []byte{0x23f32}`

> `cannot use 0x23f32 (untyped int constant 147250) as byte value in array or slice literal (overflows)`

Assuming that what you expect to get (it's not clear from your question) from something like

```
point := []byte{0x23f32 . . . }
```

is essentially

```
point := []byte{0x23,0xf3,0x2? . . . }
```

...

First, if you are trying to declare a "global" variable (e.g. a *package-scoped* variable), you need to use the `var <name> <type> = <value>` form. You can't use `<name> := <value>`.

Second, you can initialize a `[]byte` in a couple different ways:

- `var p1 []byte = []byte{ 0x12, 0x23, 0x45, . . . }`
  an array/slice of hex constants, each needs to be in the range 0x00-0xFF (0-255 decimal).
- `var p2 []byte = []byte{ "\x12\x23\x45 . . ." }`
  a string containing the desired bytes.
- `var p3 []byte = []byte{ 18, 35, 69 . . . }`
  an array/slice of decimal constants
- `var p4 []byte = []byte{ '\x12', '\x23', '\x45' . . . }`
  an array slice of individual byte literals. Note that if one specifies a value outside the range of a byte (0x00–0xFF, 0-255 decimal), you'll get a compile time error along the lines of:

  > `cannot use 'ш' (untyped rune constant 1096) as byte value in array or slice literal (overflows)`

Note that the above 4 examples all yield exactly the same value.

Comment: hello Nicholas, thanks for detailed answer! i think byte{ 0x12, 0x23, 0x45} is that i need. can I please ask another question: and if it is still permissible for me to use point not as a global variable, is it possible for me in this case to use just point := []byte(0x23f32...) type conversion to convert a string to a slice of bytes? I will get the same result as in the case of array/slice of hex constants { 0x12, 0x23 ... ?

Comment: the value `0x23f32...` being cast as a `[]byte` here: `point := []byte(0x23f32...)`,  is not a string: it is a hexadecimal (base-16) integer literal. It will be limited to no more than 16 hexadecimal digits (the maximum for a 64-bit integer type). If it's longer than 16 digits, something like `n int64 = 0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef`  will generate the compile time error `cannot use 0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef (untyped int constant 1512366075204170929049582354406559215) as int64 value in variable declaration (overflows)`

Comment: but due type conversion, it would be slice of bytes? i just checked this out with byte(), it's work as i expected

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert 32 bit number to bytes, you can do this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/binary"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   var point [4]byte
   binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(point[:], 0x23f32)
   fmt.Println(point) // [0 2 63 50]
}
```

https://godocs.io/encoding/binary#ByteOrder.PutUint32

Comment: Hey 048, thanks for the answer, really appreciate that! but here the problem - if I use 0x23 then everything is ok. but actually I need to use 32 bytes long value, so i get the following error

point := []byte{0x23f32 ...} // > 0x23f32 ... to 32 byte long

'cannot use 0x23f32 ... (untyped int constant 147250 ... ) as byte value in array or slice literal (overflows)'

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand what you mean by Rust float literals mixed up with Go., I mean f32 in example is just a continuation of 32 bytes, for example 0x23f32a324f12c3 ... etc., not a float literal, or are you pointing to something else?

Comment: @thereisnoalternativeDEAF see update

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to check it out now